# Why doesn't my custom cursor settings load after I shut down and open my laptop on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor

So, I customized the cursor setting, and I made my mouse look like a carrot :). But after I open my laptop back up it goes back to the default cursors.

I am able to go to the control panel and load up what I customized, but its annoying having to do that every time I get back on my laptop.

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

1. Turn off hibernation.
2. Delete the hibernation file.
3. Re-open hibernation and the system will generate a new hibernation file.
4. Reset the custom cursor settings.
5. View if the issue is resolved.